# SSH Connection refused / SSH disabled?

Tags: ssh

I know it's not much info
but look for a lot of stuff but can't understand

SSH stop working from all device (OSX, IOS, PC) I have this error

```
:.ssh kevin$ ssh pi@192.168.1.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.2 port 22: Connection refused
```

Tried `sudo rm known_hosts` but no help

When I do a scan I don't see the SSH port .... I have no clue why.

FTP is still working and VNC is kind of working (When I login I get logged out after a few sec, and can't even see the whole screen anyway)

Is the only solution is to connect the raspberry pi to a screen and reinstall SSH?

Thank you

Update :

Raspberry pi led is red

Port

```
 Open TCP Port:     21          ftp
 Open TCP Port:     53          domain
 Open TCP Port:     80          http
 Open TCP Port:     139         netbios-ssn
 Open TCP Port:     445         microsoft-ds
 Open TCP Port:     5900        rfb
```

[image: Boot folder]

Answer (score 1):

Connection refused in combination with port 22 not showing up in a port scan generally means that SSH is not enabled on the system. Reinstalling SSH probably won't help you, but you could try to re-enable it.

If you don't want to connect a screen, you can power down the pi, take the SD card out and mount in on a pc, put a file called `ssh` in the `/boot` directory and put it back in your Pi. This should enable the SSH server.

Comment: It’s seems like a great solution, where do I fine the original ssh file for the boot folder though ? Or I just create one is it ?

Comment: You don't. Just create an empty file called `ssh` there. It triggers the pi to enable the SSH server.

Comment: Unfortunately same issue, also forget to mention but the Raspberry PI led is red, I also added a screenshot of the boot folder

Comment: 1) just red LED or also LAN LEDs?  2) check if ssh is running on the system: `systemctl status ssh` 3) check if port gets blocked `iptables -L`

Comment: the ethernet was ok (one side green one orange) I have normal trafic (FTP / HTTP etc) I plugged to a screen but couldn't start the X interface. so I just formatted everything and started over... thank you.